# Validar Formularios dentro de un modal con jQuery.Validate.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-validate

Este es el modal que lo mando a llamar por PHP con `require("includes/modales/mcaracteristica.php");`. Esto con el fin de no acumular todo el código en el mismo index.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="nueva-carac">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="overlay-insCaracter"></div>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nueva Característica</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form" method="POST" id="formInscaract" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombreCaract" class="col-form-label">Nombre de característica</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreCaract" name="nombreCaract" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre de la característica">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-exclamation"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="precioCaract" class="col-form-label">Precio de característica</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precioCaract" name="precioCaract" placeholder="Ingrese el precio de la característica">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-exclamation"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="catCaract">Categoría</label>
                        <select class="custom-select form-control-border" id="catCaract" name="catCaract">
                            <option disabled selected>Seleccionar</option>
                            <?php while($rowcat = $rcatego->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rowcat['id_categoria']?>"><?php echo $rowcat['nombre_categoria']?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-exclamation"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group float-right">
                        <input type="submit" id="btninsCaract" class="btn btn-info " value="Insertar característica">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y tengo implementado el jquery.validate, importo su libreria en el index.php ya probe poner el script en el index, y dentro de un archivo js pero en ninguno valida los input del formulario. También lo puse dentro del ajax que es el que efectúa el INSERT pero tampoco lo valida. Incluso utilizando el simple atributo `required` de HTML lo deja pasar.
Este es el javascript de la validación:

```
$('#nueva-carac form').validate({
        rules: {
          nombreCaract:{
            required: true,
          },
          precioCaract: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
          },
          catCaract: {
            required: true,
          },
        },
        messages: {
          nombreCaract:{
            required: "Ingrese el nombre de la característica."
          },
          precioCaract: {
            required: "Ingrese el precio de la característica.",
            number: "Ingrese un valor numérico válido."
          },
          catCaract: {
            required: "Ingrese la categoría al cual pertenece la característica.",
          },
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
          element.closest('.input-group').append(error);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        }
    });
```

¿Cómo hago para poner la validación dentro de un modal?

Comment: ¿Tienes algún evento para detectar el envío del formulario o clic en el botón de envío?

Comment: Hola @Triby si, tengo el ajax en ese boton para enviar los datos.

Comment: Tengo el evento click

Comment: Es es el problema, porque el clic se ejecuta antes del evento `submit`, que es donde realmente se hace la validación. Solo cambia el evento del botón a `$('#nueva-carac form').on('submit', function() { /* Aquí validas el formulario */});`

Comment: @Triby Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!